# Evaluation of $\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{x^2+2x}{\ln(x+1)}dx$

Tags: integration

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{0}\frac{x^2+2x}{\ln(x+1)}dx$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$I = \int_{-1}^{0}\frac{x^2+2x}{\ln(x+1)}dx\;,$$ Put $x+1=t\; $ Then $dx = dt$ and changing limits, we get

$$I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^2-1}{\ln t}dt$$

Now how can i solve after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Try $u=\ln t$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{I} & = \int_{-1}^{0}{x^{2} + 2x \over \ln\pars{x + 1}}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{2} - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
-\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{2} - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{y}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{y} - x^{y + 2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over y + 1} - {1 \over y + 3}}\,\dd y =
\left.\ln\pars{y + 1 \over y + 3}\right\vert_{\ y\ =\ 0}^{\,y\ \to\ \infty} =
\color{#f00}{\ln\pars{3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

The integral $$I(x) := \int_0^1 \frac{t^x - 1}{\ln(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t$$ has derivative $$I'(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{t^x \ln(t)}{\ln(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{x+1},$$ as well as the particular value $I(0) = \int_0^1 0 \, \mathrm{d}t = 0$, so it is $$I(x) = \ln(x+1).$$ In particular, $$I(2) = \int_0^1 \frac{t^2 - 1}{\ln(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t = \ln(3).$$

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, indeed !

Answer (score 3):

By setting $t=e^{-z}$,
$$ I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^2-1}{\log t}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-z}-e^{-3z}}{z}\,dz = \color{red}{\log(3)}$$
by [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html).

Answer (score 1):

Considering the antiderivative $$I=\int\frac{x^2+2x}{\ln(x+1)}dx$$ us $$\log(x+1)=t\implies x=e^t-1\implies dx=e^t dt$$ So, $$I=\int\frac{e^ {3t}-e^t} t dt=3\int\frac{e^ {3t}} {3t}dt-\int\frac{e^ {t}} {t}dt$$ Now, we face the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $$I=\text{Ei}(3 t)-\text{Ei}(t)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\ln t$.

$\displaystyle I=\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{e^{2u}-1}{u}\,u\,\mathrm du=\int_{-\infty}^0\left(e^{2u}-1\right)\,\mathrm du$.

Now, please try to continue.